# Error in function: get() can't be applied to a string (python)

Tags: python, pandas, function

let's suppose that my dataset looks like this:

| ID | School Name | School Type | Class size | Specialization |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | New Jersey State School | State School | 7000 | General |
| 1 | American International School | Private International School | 200 | STEM |
| 2 | Boston Arts High School | Private National School | 500 | Arts |
| 3 | New Hamptons Academy | Private National School | 300 | Humanities |
| 4 | Colorado State School | State School | 10000 | General |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have some key values being defined:

```
school_type_key={'State School':0, 'Private National School':1, 'Private International School':2}
specialization_key={'STEM':0,'Humanities':1,'Arts':2, 'Life Sciences':3, 'General':4, 'Other':5}
```

I need to write a function that:

1. takes a column
2. makes a list of unique value
3. sorts this list based on defined keys
4. returns a list

Here is what I tried:

```
def sort_by_keys(column):
    unique_values=df[column].unique()
    unique_values=list(unique_values)
    key=column.replace(' ','_').lower()+'_key'

    #I need key so that if i pass 'School Type' column, it is sorted by 'school_type_key'

    unique_values.sort(key=key.get, reverse=True)
    return unique_values

sort_by_keys('School Type')
```

However, it returns an error because key is a string and 'get' can't be applied towards a string. How can I solve this issue?

Expected output:

```
output=sort_by_keys('School Type')
print(output)
['State School', 'Private National School', 'Private International School']

output=sort_by_keys('Specialization')
print(output)
['STEM', 'Humanities','Arts','General']
```

Comment: What is the expected output for your input data, please?

Comment: @Sheetal I did, in the end, check please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
MAPPING = {
    'School Type': school_type_key,
    'Specialization': specialization_key
}

def sort_by_keys(col):
    return (df[col].sort_values(key=lambda x: x.map(MAPPING[col]))
                   .unique().tolist())
```

Output:

```
>>> sort_by_keys('School Type')
['State School', 'Private National School', 'Private International School']

>>> sort_by_keys('Specialization')
['STEM', 'Humanities', 'Arts', 'General']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. But based on your dictionary `school_type_key`, this could work for you.:

```
import pandas as pd
school_type_key={'State School':0, 'Private National School':1, 'Private International School':2}
df = pd.DataFrame({'School Type': school_type_key.keys()})
def sort_by_keys(column):
    return df[column].to_list()[::-1]
sort_by_keys('School Type')
```

Result:

```
['Private International School', 'Private National School', 'State School']
```